# NullPointerException on SharedPreferences in Button OnClick

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to update a shared preference of whether or not a user has checked a box to not display a welcome screen anymore. I access my shared preferences my onClick listener for a button. I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception and I don't know how to fix it?

Here is my code....

```
public class WelcomeScreenActivity extends Activity {


SharedPreferences mPrefs;
final String welcomeScreenShownPref = "welcomeScreenShown";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.welcomescreen);


    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.welcomecontinue);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.welcomecheckbox);
            if(cb.isChecked()){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, true);
                editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference
                Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if(!cb.isChecked()){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(welcomeScreenShownPref, false);
                editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference
                Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });


}

}
```

Can anyone shed some light into this?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever set mPrefs in that example you've included.

Comment: At what line is the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs;
```

You have never initialized it. Although you are using it

```
mPrefs.edit();
```

Do do something like:

```
SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Before using it.

Comment: I have tried `SharedPreferences mPrefs = new SharedPreferences();` but it errors and says "Cannot instantiate the type SharedPreferences"

Comment: Would `your_prefs` be `welcomeScreenShown` in my case?

Comment: I guess so, give it a try

Comment: Did you call it in the onCreate?

Comment: I did and it fixed that error. Now I am getting a `[2013-12-23 13:19:54 - ddms] null
java.lang.NullPointerException` Error. No clue what that is

Comment: Just needed to restart eclipse! Thanks and the correct solution was `SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

Answer (score 3):

You are never setting `mPrefs` to anything s calling `mPrefs.edit()` will throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: I have tried `SharedPreferences mPrefs = new SharedPreferences();` but it errors and says "Cannot instantiate the type SharedPreferences"

Comment: Use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` instead.

Comment: `SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` Threw a NULL error.

Comment: Does it return null or throw a NullPointerException?

Does `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());` work?

Comment: it threw a NullPointerException if it was declared outside of OnCreate()